# How to find errors that referenced in Error logs?

Tags: logging

I am one of the Sitecore developer of a large Sitecore site, I have been assigned to clean up a project that cleans up a lot of the error logs, These are the errors logs, but since I am new to the project I cant find where these data sources are referenced, also this is a huge site, so clicking each item and checking is not a go.

**Logs**

```
NOT A VALID DATASOURCE ERRORS

//55 TIMES
6752 11:37:28 WARN  '{E99DFA50-A1F7-4534-B728-6D36DA85FEEB}' is not valid datasource.


//52 TIMES
//THESE 3 ALWAYS AT THE SAME TIME, SHOULD BE ON SAME PAGE
4856 11:38:19 WARN  '{8928869D-C464-44B9-BC5D-A9910FDFF69D}' is not valid datasource.
4856 11:38:19 INFO  view /Views/Render/check/HTML/Hshotthere.cshtml does not have any version of the data source item
4856 11:38:19 WARN  '{57C4C5FF69DE-4D88-ADEC-FACCFF69D383A27B3}' is not valid datasource.


//11 TIMES
7144 11:32:29 WARN  '{FF69D-21FF69D98-4FEF-BB0E-88A107FF69DA21382}' is not valid
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with the **Broken Links** report in Sitecore PowerShell Extensions.

- Install the latest version of Sitecore PowerShell Extensions
- In the reporting menu, find the `Broken Links` report:
  [image]
- Select the home page or site root you want to search. Make sure you only select `Internal Links`:

[image]

- Look in the report for broken links in the `__Final Renderings` field.

[image]

That will give you all the places where a datasource item is being referenced, that no longer exists. As for fixing, that is probably a more manual process.